# open a new tab and don't lose focus

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I'm Using javascript, I want to open a new page in a different tab, but remain focused on the current tab. I know I can do it like this:

**JS**

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", openNewBackgroundTab, false);

function openNewBackgroundTab(){
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = "http://www.3nytechnology.com/";
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");    
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, false, 0, null);
    a.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a id="test" href="http://www.stupidcodes.com" target="_blank" >Open Google</a>
```

but this code is not working in FireFox 26.0

can any one help me to solve this problem....

Comment: You can't reliably tell a browser on what tab it's focus should be. It's not possible.

Comment: Try to attach the eventListener after you declare your function openNewBackgroundTab.

Comment: thats seriously very bad user experience..

Comment: its working fine at some where i just want to make the same but i didn't fine any use full link http://www.mediafire.com/download/5nj0w6s53belsp1/netsute.mp4  just click in black color division

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by simulating <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + click event

```
function openNewBackgroundTab() {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = "http://www.google.com/";
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    //the tenth parameter of initMouseEvent sets ctrl key
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, false, 0, null);
    a.dispatchEvent(evt);   
}
```

Tested only on chrome.

Comment: You are right but this is only working in chrome what about other browser like...
• Safari
• Firefox
• IE9+

Comment: It is not working in my chrome.. may be in new updates..